# Not able to resolve localhost, but 127.0.0.1

Tags: localhost

I am able to visit 127.0.0.1. When visiting localhost, it is not able to resolve.

Here is /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost # suppose to list all folder + files under /var/www, when visit localhost.

127.0.0.1       mymachine # aegir

127.0.0.1       languages.local #drupal 

127.0.0.1       languages.localhost #drupal

-- The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Could you please also add the terminal output of: "host localhost"
And what happens when you try to visit mymachine

Comment: Try to `ping localhost` and try to chmod **etc/hosts** to **644**

Answer (score 0):

Need to know what "visit" means, please - are you referring to typing `http://localhost` into the address bar in a browser?  If so, *which* browser?  Are you typing the `http://` part in, or only typing `localhost`?

Also, please post output from the following:

`ping -c 1 127.0.0.1 ; ping -c localhost ; host localhost`

Comment: This is comment, not an answer. Someone with that much rep should know it already.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, you just necro'd a *five year old* answer of mine to complain that "someone with that much rep should know better" than to have phrased it as an answer rather than a comment.  

Ahem.

Comment: Those are the perils of using the Android SE app before my morning *espresso*. The stupid app shows answers in a way that make no sense. This one appeared as being "new" and I didn't pay attention to the (very pale gray) date. Sorry.